# Ajax jquery confusion

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

This is probably straight forward but I'm a newbie and I need help!
If I make an Ajax request which when successful replaces a section of the DOM with other data, how do I make the new data accessable to jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

the Data will be available in the parameter you pass to the callback function

```
$.ajax( {
type:'Get',
url:'http://mysite.com/mywebservice',
sucess:function(data) {
 alert(data);
}

})
```

Which you could also express using the Ajax shorthand `get`

```
$.get('http://mysite.com/mywebservice', function (data) {
 alert(data);
});
```

And if you mean how to access the data after you injected it to the DOM, then it will be automatically accessible because it becomes a part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In the callback function you provide to the ajax request, you will have access to the data. From there you can replace part of the DOM with it and/or store it somewhere else (global variable, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the replaced area have no event handlers bound, of course, unless you use jquery 1.3's new live() events.